# Android: Weird crash message on method call

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I've designed app for Android and get occasional reports for crashes:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

at this line in source code :

```
int y = -(int)(fft.freqToIndex(freq)/DrawXStep*DrawXMult); // Calculate bin
```

I'm trying to isolate possible causes for this error. The only one that comes to my mind is that object fft was not properly initialized and method is not accessible.

Is there any other possible source for NullPointerException in this line from source code ?

Thanks in advance,
regards,
Bor.

Comment: first check whether you are really getting the value in fft.freqToIndex(freq),DrawXStep,DrawXMult using log above this statement

Comment: Or break the statement apart into multiple lines so you can see which element is throwing a `NullPointerException`

Comment: DrawXStep,DrawXMult are global variables - I guess they cannot raise this error ? Am I right that only fft.freqToIndex can return this exception ? This method always return some value...

Answer (score 0):

**java.lang.NullPointerException**  means that some object you're using had null as a value.
you should debug and find the end source of the problem. Place a breakpoint on the line  `int y = -(int)(fft.freqToIndex(freq)/DrawXStep*DrawXMult);` and  step into the method and find out where the process went wrong , remember that you can peek at the current value of your variables just by hovering on it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other possible source for NullPointerException in this line from source code ?

Yes, if any of `freq`, `DrawXStep` or `DrawXMult` are objects such as `Integer` or `Double` and the value is `null`. Autounboxing the value will cause an NPE.